# execute function after one completed

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions

I have two functions in plugins and I want second function to run only after first executes completely: How can I call second function from first?

Both functions are attached to publish post / update post

Function one:

```
add_action("save_post", "save_afift_meta_box", 1, 3);
function save_afift_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update){
 some code...
}
```

Second function:

```
add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'xyz_link_smap_future_to_publish', 20, 3 );
function xyz_link_smap_future_to_publish($new_status, $old_status, $post){
 some code...
}
```

Comment: It would be better, if you explain and show code of what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source [`wp-includes/post.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L0), then you'll see that `wp_transition_post_status()`, which contains `transition_post_status`, at both occurrences, in `wp_insert_post()` and `wp_publish_post()`, is called before the `save_post` hook. In short, the order is just different than you want it to be.